# tools:ignore not working xml

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to ignore typos in xml attributes with `tools:ignore` but it's not working...

Any ideas why not?

**Note: I don't want to disable Typo check globally, just specific attributes of specific files**

What I've tried:

```
<TextView
    tools:ignore="all"
    android:id="@+id/labl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

where `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

and:

```
<!--suppress all -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

(Note the `labl` gives the typo warning)

I've tried a couple of files but each yielded the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Inspections > Spelling > Typo and uncheck it.[image]

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to disable for every file, just specific attributes of specific files.